# build.gradle "a newer version of xxxx" is available

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, basegameutils

I'm getting a warning in the BaseGameUtils build.gradle file like so:

[image]

I'm trying to understand the warning I'm getting regarding the version number.  In the dependencies, I'm using '20.0+' and the error tells me that there is a later version than 24.0.0 available.

I previously changed the Google Play Services version from 10.0.0 to 10.2.0 and upped the minSDKVersion so that they matched and everything is OK on that side of things but I just can't understand how to fix this support library warning (the Google Play Services version wasn't using a '+' appended, not sure if that makes any difference)  The way I understand it is that the '+' is saying that it requires 'version 20.0.0 or any later version'.

Where is 24.0.0 coming from?  How can I get rid of this warning?

Grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction